# What happens to QVector's item when it's deleted elsewhere?

Tags: qt, pointers, vector

I'm wondering about what happens when I delete a QVector's item?

1. Is it automatically removed from the
   QVector?
2. Do I have to remove it manually?

Also, how can I find out the index of an iteration of the iterator?

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `QVector<Thing*>` and `delete` one of the `Thing`s that stored in it, it will *not* be removed automatically from the vector. You need to do that yourself.

As far as I know, and from what I read in the docs, none of the `QVector` iterators has a method to tell at what index it is positioned.

But if you have a reference to the vector itself (or at least to it's `begin()` iterator), you can use:

```
int position = iter - v.begin();
```

Comment: So I have to iterate through the elements with a for loop or similar. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: that's one way of doing it. depends on what you're after really.

Comment: If you got an STL iterator iter, you can just use iter-v.begin() to compute the index of the element iter points to.

Comment: @Christian: thanks, always forget about that. Qt's iterators support that too.